# how to display the images of a product inserted by laravel voyager?

Tags: laravel, voyager

i have a product table, where there is a multi images field, i insert a product with these images by laravel voyager, i try to display these images of a product but too bad it doesn't work.

```
<ul class="hide-bullets">
                            @if ($products->images)
                             @foreach (json_decode($products->images, true) as $images)
                                <li class="col-sm-3">
                                    <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-16">
                                        <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$products->images) }}">
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                             @endforeach
                            @endif
                        </ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

Check [here](https://voyager-docs.devdojo.com/core-concepts/helper-methods) about helper method to display images.

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    $images = json_decode($post->images);
    @foreach($images as $image)
        <img src="{{ Voyager::image($post->getThumbnail($image, 'small')) }}" />
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)